# Deleting last vertex using ArcMap Keyboard Shortcut?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to delete the last vertex created when making a line or polygon in ArcMap?

Basically the same functionality as right clicking and then picking "Delete Vertex"

Comment: Ctrl+Z similar to many others

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> is the standard Windows shortcut for undo, which works in ArcGIS Desktop.

See [Keyboard shortcuts that can be used while editing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/keyboard-shortcuts-that-can-be-used-while-editing.htm)

Also have a look at [Keyboard shortcuts in ArcMap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/keyboard-shortcuts-in-arcmap.htm) for more shortcuts that will work in ArcGIS, and the printable [ArcGIS Desktop Tips and Shortcuts](http://www.esri.com/LIBRARY/BROCHURES/PDFS/ARCGIS-DESKTOP-TIPS.PDF) PDF.

Answer (score 0):

As I was working on ArcMap 10.1 and 10.2 there was also a <kbd>**Backspace**</kbd> key working to delete last vertices, while continuing drawing. I guess it should be available in other versions too.